# Creating Dynamic Routes from data NuxtJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

How can I convert this data into the following routes in Nuxt, I can see from examples it's quite easy with a unique id but with un-unique data like make/model is that possible?

```
/_make/_model/_memory
```

for example

```
/Apple/iPhone-8/64GB
```

Data:

```
 {
    "id": 1,
    "make": "Apple",
    "model": "iPhone 8",
    "memory": 64,
 },
 {
    "id": 2,
    "make": "Apple",
    "model": "iPhone X",
    "memory": 64,
 },
 {
    "id": 3,
    "make": "Samsung",
    "model": "S20",
    "memory": 128,
 },
```

Ideally that would create a page for each phone as well as model and make pages?

Would this be the correct way to use axios?

```
  generate: {
    routes() {
      return axios.get(`${process.env.API_URL}/phones`)
      .then((res) => {
        return res.data.map((phone) => {
          return {
            route: `/${phone.makeCanonical}/${phone.modelCanonical}/${phone.memory}GB`,
            payload: phone
          }
        })
      })
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `generate.routes` function of the [Nuxt config](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate/#routes).  This example is using the `payload` return property to speed things up.

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    make: 'Apple',
    model: 'iPhone 8',
    memory: 64
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    make: 'Apple',
    model: 'iPhone X',
    memory: 64
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    make: 'Samsung',
    model: 'S20',
    memory: 128
  }
]

export default {
  generate: {
    routes() {
      return data.map(item => ({
        route: `/${item.make}/${item.model}/${item.memory}`,
        payload: item
      }))
    }
  }
}
```

This will create a page for every configuration of make, model, and memory.  To make a page just for each make, or just for each model, you just need to add additional `{ route, payload }` objects for the pages you'd like.  You'll of course need page components set up to handle each `route` you return as well.

Then, inside your page component:

```
async asyncData ({ params, error, payload }) {
    if (payload) return { phone: payload }
    else return { phone: await backend.fetchPhone(params.make, params.model, params.memory) }
}
```

As of the last time I used this, it's required to check for the `payload` property in asyncData due to the way Nuxt currently handles static generation.  See [this](https://github.com/nuxt/rfcs/issues/22) issue for an explanation.